# How can I generate classes from outside XSD file using JAXB XJC

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I have two projects:

A
 /src/main/resources/schema.xsd
 pom.xml

B
/src/main/gen
pom.xml

I want in B project generate classes from XSD, that exists in A Project

In pom.xml of B project I have:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>xjc</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xjc</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/gen</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

But xsd file is not found in classpath:

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.5:xjc (xjc) on project B: No schemas have been found

How can I use xsd from another project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with this configuration is that `<schemaDirectory>` expects a `File` name/path. The thing about `File` is that it looks for files on the file system, searching from the current working directory. In which case the project root. But the resource from project A is not in the `src/main/resources` of the project B. It is a classpath resource, of which (when build in maven), the `src/main/resources` doesn't even exist anymore.

I've never tried to do with with the [**jaxb2-maven-plugin**](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html#schemaFiles), so I am not sure if it is possible.

But with the [**maven-jaxb2-plugin**](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide), it allows [**Compiling a schema from a Maven artifact**](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-CompilingaschemafromaMavenartifact). You could so something like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <dependencyResource>
                    <groupId>projecta.groupid</groupId>
                    <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <resource>/schema.xsd</resource>
                </dependencyResource>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
        <generateDirectory>src/main/gen/</generateDirectory>
        <generatePackage>mypackage</generatePackage> 
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In which case, it's resource (schema.xsd) is in the `src/main/resources` of project A. The plugin will generate the class files to the `mypackage` package and sources the `src/main/gen`

Comment: Brilliant, but i want to know if with jaxb2-maven-plugin that is also possible.

Comment: I have never tried, but browsing through the [configuration options](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html), I don't see anything that leads me to believe this is possible. That's just from me skimming the guide. For all I know, it _may_ be possible. I mean theoretically you could use an absolute path from the project A, but I think that defeats the purpose of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @peeskillet Author of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` here. Please see my answer, I guess there's a couple of features you might find useful. :)

Answer (score 7):

My [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide) supports [separate schema compilation](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Separateschemacompilation).

How to do this:

- Add your artifact `a` as episode.
- If `a.xsd` is imported into `b.xsd`, you have to make this schema available to JAXB when compiling `b`:

  - One way to do this is to extract `a.xsd` from the artifact `a` using Maven dependency plugin, for instance.
  - Another way would be to use a catalog file to rewrite the location of `a.xsd` into the artifact `a`

See [this test project](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/tree/master/tests/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82) for example.

The project [`a`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/tree/master/tests/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82/a) is totally unspectacular. Just compiles the schema `a.xsd`.

The project [`b`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/tree/master/tests/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82/b) is more interesting. Let's take a look.

[`pom.xml`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/blob/master/tests/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82/b/pom.xml#L28-L34):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.cat</catalog>
                <episodes>
                    <episode>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin-tests-MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82-a</artifactId>
                    </episode>
                </episodes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The configuration says use the artifact `a` as episode. So when JAXB/XJC meets classes compiled in `a`, it will reuse them instead of generating new ones.

By the way, you can use the [`useDependenciesAsEpisodes`](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Separateschemacompilation) instead of configuring individual episodes. In this case all the dependencies will be treated as episodes which is very convenient (less configuration).

The configuration also says to use [the catalog file](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/blob/master/tests/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82/b/src/main/resources/catalog.cat#L5):

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.ab.org" "maven:org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-tests-MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82-a:jar::!"
```

This instructs JAXB/XJC to rewrite all schema URLs starting with `http://www.ab.org` to start with  `maven:org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-tests-MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82-a:jar::!` instead. The latter will be processed by the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` and finally resolved to the resource in `a`.

Let's take a closer look. The schema [`b.xsd`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/blob/master/tests/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82/b/src/main/resources/b.xsd) [imports `http://www.ab.org/a.xsd`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/blob/master/tests/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82/b/src/main/resources/b.xsd#L8):

```
<import namespace="urn:a" schemaLocation="http://www.ab.org/a.xsd"/>
```

This will be rewritten to `maven:org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-tests-MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82-a:jar::!/a.xsd` which will be resolved to the `a.xsd` inside the JAR of the project `a`. So, finally, JAXB/XJC will be able to read this schema from the `a`'s JAR artifact.

You can also use `PUBLIC` instead of `REWRITE_SYSTEM` to reference `a.xsd` per namespace URI instead of schema location (which is logically better):

```
PUBLIC "urn:a" "maven:org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-tests-MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-82-a:jar::!/a.xsd"
```

However there's a [bug in JAXB/XJC](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-942) this does not work if you have `schemaLocation` in your `xs:import`.

This would work at the moment:

```
<xsd:import namespace="urn:a"/>
```

This won't work at the moment:

```
<xsd:import namespace="urn:a" schemaLocation="a.xsd"/>
```

I've sent Oracle a [pull request](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/pull/8) which fixes that but it's not applied yet.

The explanation above applies to the [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin) and works in versions [0.10.0](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/releases/tag/0.10.0) and higher.

Your original question is about [`jaxb2-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/) from Codehaus which is a different Maven plugin. This plugin does not have all the features I've described above, but at least episodes should work via [arguments](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html#arguments). [Catalogs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html#catalog) must also work, but I believe, `jaxb2-maven-plugin` does not support resolving schemas in Maven artifacts. You can use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to extract `a.xsd` from artifact `a` instead.

SO disclaimer: I am the author of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

Note for reviewers: it is NOT my intention here to push/advertise my plugin, I just want to provide a solution to the asked question. And it appears that my project offers the best/most elegant and full solution.

Answer (score -2):

We can also use as below in pom.xml file

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>id1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        <packageName>com.subu.xsd.model</packageName>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/java/schemadir</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaFiles>XYZ.xsd</schemaFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```